# How to programmatically send Facebook Group invite

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-group

I would like to create a page that can prompt for login if the user has not logged into facebook, then check if the user is a member of a group. if not, provide a button that when clicked will send a group invite to this user.

I'm able to do everything until the last step on sending group invite. I would like to know if it is even possible. the group is an ordinary Open group, not an app group which the docs say is still in beta.

I console.log the response and saw that I keep getting the following error when button was clicked.

```
Object {error: Object}
error: Object
code: 3
message: "(#3) "
type: "OAuthException"
```

The error code and error message isn't helpful at all...

here's the full code I have so far

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Group Tester</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css" />
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body.connected #login { display: none; }
        body.connected #logout { display: block; }
        body.not_connected #login { display: block; }
        body.not_connected #logout { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout(function() { window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 100);"></body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
</script>
<script>
var uid = "";
var fbName = "";
var accessToken = "";
var appId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var appSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var appAccessToken = "";
var groupId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#group").hide();
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({ appId: appId, 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true});

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', handleResponseChange); 
        checkLoginStatus();
    };
});
function handleResponseChange(response) {
    document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';

    if (response.authResponse) {
        checkLoginStatus();
    }
}

function loginUser() {    
    FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email, user_likes, manage_groups, user_groups'});     
}

function checkLoginStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            document.body.className = 'connected';
            uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                loginSuccess(response);
            });
        } else {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            notLoggedIn();
        }
    });
}

function checkGroupMember()
{
    var fql = "SELECT uid from group_member WHERE uid=me() AND gid='"+groupId+"'";
    var fqlencoded = encodeURIComponent(fql);
    FB.api("/fql?q="+fqlencoded, 
        function(response) {
            //console.log(response.data[0].uid);
            if (response.data.length != 0)
            {
                $("#sendInvite").hide();
                $("#alreadyMember").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#sendInvite").show();
                $("#alreadyMember").hide();
            }
        }
    );
}

function logoutUser() {
    FB.logout();
    notLoggedIn();
}

function loginSuccess(response) {
    $("#profileName").html(response.name);
    fbName = response.name;
    $("#profileImg").html("<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/"+uid+"/picture?type=large' />");
    $("#group").show();
    console.log("logged in");
    checkGroupMember();
}

function notLoggedIn() {
    document.body.className = 'not_connected';
    $("#profileImg").html("");
    $("#profileName").html("");
    $("#group").hide();
}

function sendInvite()
{
    var connection = '/'+groupId+'/members/'+uid;
    console.log(connection);
    console.log(accessToken);
    FB.api(connection, 'post', {access_token : accessToken}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

</script>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <center><h1>Group API Test</h1></center>
    <div id="login" onClick="loginUser();"></div>
    <div id="logout" onClick="logoutUser();"></div>
    <br />
    <div id="group">
        <div id="profileImg"></div>
        <div id="profileName"></div>
        <div id="sendInvite" style="display:none;" onclick="sendInvite()">Send Invite Now</div>
        <div id="alreadyMember" style="display:none;">Already a Member</div>
        <div id="message"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The authentication flow works just fine, problem is at the sendInvite() function and I'm open to suggestions.

oh..., if anyone wants the css file for this code. (not that it matters to the question)

```
body {
    text-align: center; 
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222222;
}

h1 {
    color: #34D13C;
    margin-top:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 3px 0 #222222;
}

#login
{
    width: 413px;
    height: 70px;
    background-image:url('../img/login.png');
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#logout
{
    width: 413px;
    height: 70px;
    background-image:url('../img/logout.png');
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#sendInvite
{
    background-color: cyan;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: black thin solid;
    margin-top:10px;
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#sendInvite:hover
{
    background-color: skyblue;
    color : green;
}
```

Comment: facing same issue. did u find any solution ??